# help! apt-get using using wrong architecture - arm64 instead of amd64

Tags: apt, configuration, architecture

I was trying to setup a cross compiler for arm64. I found a set of instructions that I thought might work. Instead I ended up messing up my apt-get configuration. Can someone help me?

When I do an apt-get update now, I see:

Ign:17 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main **arm64** Packages
etc..

instead of

Ign:17 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main **amd64** Packages

How can I set the correct architecture for apt-get?

Comment: What "set of instructions"?

Comment: To remove arm64 packages and arch from amd64 machine, goal is to remove all packages and architecture. Traces of which can be found with:

dpkg -l | grep arm64

sudo apt-get remove *:arm64
sudo dpkg --remove-architecture arm64